# Redis: How to access keys in specific keyspace

Tags: redis

I have 2 keyspaces in my redis server:

```
db0:keys=1,expires=0
db1:keys=36679593,expires=0
```

But if I run

```
redis-cli KEYS '*'
```

I only get keys in db0. How can i search the keys in db1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `redis-cli` with the `-n` option;

```
$ redis-cli -n 1 KEYS '*'

$ redis-cli --help
redis-cli 2.6.7

Usage: redis-cli [OPTIONS] [cmd [arg [arg ...]]]
  ...
  -n <db>          Database number
  ...
```

Answer (score 8):

first, you need to select the `db1`. To do that use `select 1`.
Then you can get all keys using `KEYS *`

```
select 1 // selects db 1

keys * // search all keys in selected db (db -1 )
```